# kafka + description of the leaders and replications one of the leader not exists

Tags: apache-kafka

we have ( **3 kafka machines** )

kafka brokers id's - are ( **101 , 102 ,103** )

ambari version - 2.6.1

hadoop version 2.6.5

29 datanode machines

3 journal machines ( master machines )

when we run the following command

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.231.23.45:2181 –describe
```

we see the description of the leaders and replications

but what is wrong here is we see only two leaders for each topic

in our case the topic name - **MLK_PLW_QA** , but the same situation is on all the topics

```
Topic:MLK_PLW_QA    PartitionCount:100  ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.bytes=9239504949
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 0    Leader: 102 Replicas: 102,101,103   Isr: 101,102,103
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 1    Leader: 102 Replicas: 103,102,101   Isr: 101,102
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 2    Leader: 101 Replicas: 101,103,102   Isr: 101,102,103
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 3    Leader: 102 Replicas: 102,103,101   Isr: 101,102,103
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 4    Leader: 101 Replicas: 103,101,102   Isr: 101,102
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 5    Leader: 101 Replicas: 101,102,103   Isr: 101,102,103
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 6    Leader: 102 Replicas: 102,101,103   Isr: 101,102,103
    Topic: MLK_PLW_QA   Partition: 7    Leader: 102 Replicas: 103,102,101   Isr: 101,102
```

I must to say that this situation not appears before couple days , and we see all leaders 101 , 102 , 103 ( from kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.231.23.45:2181 –describe )

what are the reasons that broker id - 103 not appears as leader ?

note - all kafka brokers services are running ( we can see that from ambari gui )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility, node with broker id 103 may be crashed/stopped or was down for a while. So cluster did a rebalance and selected the new leader from available nodes. Even though now broker 103 is alive, cluster controller didn't change  the leadership of topics to optimize the computing.

Comment: yes , after I review on the server.log in kafka03 we saw that - INFO [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-103], Shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread) , but we not understand what cause the broker to shutdown ( I will open a new thred about this question )